# How to get the last modified person name in query?

Tags: apex, trigger

I am using after update trigger. There I wanna fetch the user name which has modified the record. Please let me know if anyone has idea ow to achieve this.

Answer (score 2):

**If you want to get the current user who edited the record.**

You can get the current user's i.e. the user who modified the record's username by using

```
UserInfo.getUserName();
```

Using [UserInfo](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_userinfo.htm) class you can get other required information.

**To get Last Modified User and not current user.**

Last modified user will  be different from current user because that record wouldn't have been committed to the database yet.

You can get that information by using either of the below approaches

- Get the `LastModifiedId's` of all records and query on User object to get the user's information.
- Query on the same record with `LastModifiedBy.Username` field as related field won't be available in the context variables

  `Select Id, Name, Lastmodifiedby.Username from ObjectName`

Answer (score 2):

A simple query to the `LastModifiedBy` should do the trick:

```
SELECT Id, Name, LastModifiedById, LastModifiedBy.Name, LastModifiedDate FROM Contact
```

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding the question? Not sure why I got a downvote